# this webpage has a redirect loop : In magento

Tags: magento

After updating URL Base in Magento admin form http//:www.web.com to https//:www.web.com it through error :

> this webpage has a redirect loop

Tell me please why i get this error and how remove this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Clearing all cache solved my problem.

Comment: cache of what? browser? db? webserver?

Comment: I got this error right after installation while accessing admin panel

Answer (score 5):

If you edit the `secure/unsecure` base url for you Magento site you may find yourself, in a never ending loop. Perform the following steps to solve it:

1. Log in to your database using phpMyadmin or similar.
2. Find the table labelled `core_config_data`
3. Edit the rows entitled `web/unsecure/base_url` and
   `web/secure/base_url`
4. Edit the row `web/url/redirect_to_base` to `0` instead of `1`
5. Clear contents of both `var/cache` and
   `var/sessions` folders.

**[EDIT]**

Your URL should be like `http://www.web.com/` with trailing slash.

```
Site relocation issues:
```

1. Forgetting the trailing slash on the `baseURLs`
2. changing the rewritebase in `.htaccess`
3. check file/folder permissions and change so server can write to the
   directory tree especially `var/` and `media/`
4. `app/etc/local.xml` changes so Magento can access the new database

After fixing these things, clear **Cache**.

Comment: i updated into web/url/redirect_to_base from 1 to 0 but still showing error

Comment: 'Your URL should be like http//:www.web.com/ with trailing slash at the end' worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you dont have any unwanted .xml files in /app/etc/ folder.

values in local.xml files will be overwritten by other files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by setting web/cookie/cookie_lifetime in core_config_data table to 3600.

Answer (score 0):

Had this problem on Magento2 after switching to https.

Check `web/secure/use_in_adminhtml` and `web/secure/use_in_frontend` settings in `core_config_data`, they both should be set to `1`. It solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

delete cookies for domain, it wored for me in case of infinite 302 loops

Answer (score 0):

Remove var folder from Magento root.
It has solved my problem